# Lists as values in a dictionary Python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
ddic = {'a': 10,'b': 23,'c': [0, 1, 2]}
n2 = ddic['c']
n2[-2] = 1000.

ddic
{'a': 10, 'b': 23, 'c': [0, 1000.0, 2]}
```

Why changing the list at which n2 is pointing, changes also the list of dict ddic, which is contained into the hash table that ddic defines?

It looks like that when you define a dict, the key-value pairs pops-in the global namespace and is not contained into the namespace defined by the hash-table structure.

Someone knows the detailed reason of this?

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Few prenotes

- Dict keys are immutable whereas values are mutable.
- When you use `=`, the new variable just references the old list

The value at key `c` is a list.  It is pointed to by the key at that place. On copying to a variable, the reference is passed. This can be confirmed by using `id`.

```
>>> id(ddic['c'])
140726603094424
>>> id(n2)
140726603094424
```

As you see both the variables are pointing to the same element in memory. Hence any changes you make in one are reflected to the original one also.

To have a shallow copy of the list you can use `[:]` [as mentioned by Blckknght](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376270/lists-as-values-in-a-dictionary-pyython/29376334?noredirect=1#comment46933296_29376334)

```
>>> n2 = ddic['c'][:]
```

In python3, you can use (as mentioned by [Padraic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376270/lists-as-values-in-a-dictionary-pyython/29376334?noredirect=1#comment46933664_29376334))

```
>>> n2 = ddic['c'].copy()
```

Using `copy` module, you can prevent this from happening as in

```
>>> import copy
>>> n2 = copy.copy(ddic['c'])
>>> id(ddic['c'])
140726603094424
>>> id(n2)
140726603177640
```

Reference

- [`id`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id)
- [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)

Also note that as mentioned by [Kasra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376270/lists-as-values-in-a-dictionary-pyython/29376334?noredirect=1#comment46933178_29376334) in the comments, dicts don't have as separate space for them as they are data structures. You can find refernce in [this](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/dictobject.c?view=markup) document

Comment: Also you can note that `hash tables` have not a whitespace for them self  as they are data structure! http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/dictobject.c?view=markup

Comment: Do you mean 'dict keys are immutable'?

Comment: @RussellBorogove Oops Sorry! Twas a bad typo

Comment: There's no copying, shallow or otherwise, when you make a new reference to a list with `=`. Indeed, a shallow copy is all that's necessary in the questioner's situation: `n2 = ddic['c'][:]` works, as does `n2 = copy.copy(ddic['c'])`

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks. Have edited the answer after reading more

Comment: You only need deepcopy for nested lists.

Comment: `n2 = ddic['c'][:]` will copy the shallow list or `n2 = ddic['c'].copy()` in python3

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic trap Python beginner fall into.
Some object in Python are immutable (e.g. integer, string, tuple). Some object are mutable (e.g.: list, dictionary, instances).

If you modify a mutable object all other objects that reference that object will see the modified value.

if you don't want to modify ddic['c'] you have to make a copy

```
n2 = list(ddic['c'])
n2[-2] = 1000

ddic
{'a': 10,'b': 23,'c': [0, 1, 2]}
```

Answer (score 1):

`n2` is a reference to the list object in your dict. When you access `ddic['c']`, you are pointing to the same list object in the dict, not a copy of it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the list is neither "in" the dict nor "in" n2. Both the dict and the variable n2 hold a reference to it.